# Too many query requests in one page

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to recode one of my old application in a much better way. Its not too big but while loading it runs around 80 queries. But still loads in the browser in 2 sec. I can optimize few queries, thats ok. My question is should i be worried about this or its all fine.  What should be the average query requests for loading a page ? I want to know the standard limits.

Comment: The limit is whatever your users are willing to put up with. 2 seconds seems a bit long to be honest. Can you do any sort of caching?

Comment: There is no standard queries/pageload. Optimal is 0. Worst is timeout. Depends on what you do within your page. Btw, it will make quite a difference wether you are the only one using the page or if there's 100 people hitting your page at the same time.

Comment: If you load data for let's say multiple user, preload an array of user id and then load all the data in one query. Example.

Comment: Yes i can do that. I have read a lot about optimizing. But is it fine running 80 queries though they are not taking much. But is this safe ?

Comment: If you have nested queries in loops, then you really should be refactoring those to use joins

Comment: There are possibilities of deadlocks due to big amount of query request. There are chances. What can i do for that ?

Comment: Are you sure you need 80 queries? There are many ways to combine queries together `JOIN`ing, `UNION`s etc. Why is it 80 exactly? Can you give us examples?

Comment: I am using a db library which has a function for executing a query. I have a script which writes those query in txt. There i get all the queries written. Every page load, just by entering the url, this many queries run.

Comment: How many tables do you have? It is unusual to run a lot more queries than the total number of tables. If you run a query based on a result from a previous query, you can combine that into one query etc.. What kind of operations are you performing?

Comment: It is a ladder application. Like a ranking application. There are 10k users right now i am expecting another 5k in 6months maybe. So there are players. Who play in real but enter scores. It has a chatting zone. It shows players rank, name, skills, mathches, scores, basically hell lot of information.

Comment: What DB library? Is it and ORM tool/library? If so, they tend to do that and are inefficient by design. Go with "m02ph3u5" and "Mark Baker's" comments above. You can also take all the queries that return one single row and combine them into one stored procedure that returns all the data in one call. Otherwise, more specific list of SQL calls would be helpful. Good Luck.

Comment: Not only enter scores, but they challenge, they visit profiles, they check statistics, they check their ranks, their performance, and so on

Comment: Regardless, it should still require fewer than 80 requests IMO. I worked on huge websites and never had to run more than a dozen requests at a time.

Comment: I mean a db class. Sorry i was working on Java as well.

Comment: Just to reaffirm: yes, 80 queries on a single page is obscene. I've built some pretty knarly apps and my personal limit is 5 calls. Even that, makes me cringe. I would only go that high for pages that don't see much action, like admin pages.

Comment: I am getting a nightmare now. I will work on this. I will optimize them and still do a performance test.

Comment: Thanks guys for all your suggestions..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would begin by not touching the queries, but by measuring how much time do these take

- Database connection / database queries
- Back end processing (business) logic
- Network lags
- HTML rendering + any javascript execution

Any of these can be the culprit, or it can be even something else. Likely one of those, though. When you know what exactly is taking the time, it should point you to right direction when fixing the situation.

Doing some real performance tests to back up the numbers doesn't hurt, either...

Comment: But i would like to tackle the future problems. I know that i will come to know when something wrong happens. But i would like to take the steps now.

Comment: You would be tackling the future problems best if you run performance tests with big enough load that they identify the bottlenecks in your stack. It's not about focusing on the amount of queries.

Comment: I get that. So i shouldnt worry about queries. Its better to check performance by doing kind of stress testing to ensure everything  is fine.

Comment: Worry about the those 80 queries for sure. 80 is unacceptable by design. But Performance testing and analysis should always be the first step and top priority.

Comment: Thanks @BryanAllo, i will follow you. +1

Comment: You're welcome buddy. It might not be a bad idea to rebuild that page. It'll probably take just as long to try and fix it...LOL. All the best.

Answer (score 1):

There are no limits per page on queries. You do have timeout limits but you're obviously well within them.

If you're looping over n results, ie. in a nested data model, that's totally fine.
If you're not, I'm sure there's a reason. 2 seconds is a bit long for a page load, but I know nothing about your page of course.

There's really nothing wrong with 80ish queries on a page, I'd just ask myself the question, why?

A simple trick to find long queries, see how long the actual querying takes:

```
$start = microtime(1);
mysql_query('SELECT blah blah');
echo (microtime(1) - $start);
```

Comment: Noted. I will need this.

Answer (score 1):

There is no "standard query count" per page. You can for example, use "joins" which could potentially remove hunreds of individual queries!

However, i am more concerned about your "under 2 seconds" to load implying it's more than 1 second! If it's for public users (not an intranet for example) then that should be down to less than 0.5 seconds even on modest computers! To help achieve this ensure output buffering is ON for the whole page (set it in php.ini) as this will greatly improve page load speeds. For more info on Output Buffering & Compression see my post here: [Flushing the HTML document early - with ini_set( 'zlib.output_compression','ON')?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12935840/flushing-the-html-document-early-with-ini-set-zlib-output-compression-on/13074918#13074918)

Comment: Brilliant. I get that. Just a doubt. The queries come from approx 10k users, so how i avoid the possibility of deadlocks.

Comment: Sorry about the deadlocks question, may be that is a better google-to-ask question.

Comment: Thanks @VBAssassin for your suggestion and concept on outbut buffering.

Comment: Deadlocks? Why would deadlocks come into what i said in my answer? Yeah, i think that's for another question ;)